# Textbox in report apprears blank even after assigning value

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, null, expression, drilldown

I have a drill down report which has a Section as NULL. I want to replace it with N/A

I am using this expression in Section textbox, Row Group and Sort:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Section.Value), "N/A", Fields!Section.Value)
```

But even then report shows as below.

[image: Section field shows as blank instead of N/A]

Section Parameter:

[image: Section_Parameter]

Any idea where am I going wrong.

Comment: Check the type of `Fields!Section.Value` - then try by replacing your expression with `=IIF(IsNothing(CStr(Fields!Section.Value)), "N/A", Fields!Section.Value)`  and let me know.

Comment: @pedram: can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182633/conversion-error-while-converting-varchar-to-smallint

Comment: Sure - btw what I need to check over there...

Comment: I am getting datatype conversion error: select distinct Main_Qualification,
               Main_Qualification + '  '+ Qualification_Title As Main_Qual_Title
from dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw
where College_Year = @College_Year
and Qualification_Title not Like '%CANX%'
order by Main_Qualification + '  '+ Qualification_Title

Comment: Please provide error message and Type of `Main_Qualification` and `Qualification_Title`

Comment: Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20PA' to data type smallint. Main Qualification : Varchar(20)

Qualification_Title: Varchar(100)

Comment: Doesn't sound like this error has anything to do with the expression that you asked about in the question.  You should probably create a new question for it.