# Conversion error while converting varchar to smallint

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, varchar, sqldatatypes

Main Qualification : Varchar(20)

Qualification_Title: Varchar(100)

Query:

```
select distinct Main_Qualification,
               Main_Qualification + '  '+ Qualification_Title As Main_Qual_Title
from dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw
where College_Year = @College_Year
and Qualification_Title not Like '%CANX%'
order by Main_Qualification + '  '+ Qualification_Title
```

when I execute it I am getting error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20PA' to datatype smallint

dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw:

```
SELECT     dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.College_Year, dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.Learner_ID, 
           dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.Main_Qualification_Code, 
           dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.IS_AS_Level_Umbrella, 
           dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.IS_A2_Level_Umbrella, 
           dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.Main_Qualification, 
           dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw.Qualification_Title, 
           dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw.Qualification_Mgmnt_Code_1, 
           dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw.Section
,dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw.Qualification_Mgmnt_Code_2
,dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.Code
FROM         dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw INNER JOIN
             dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw ON 
             dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw.Qualification_Code = dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.Main_Qualification_Code AND 
             dbo.IM_LU_Qualifications_vw.Qualification_Year = dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw.College_Year
```

[dbo].[IM_EN_Main_Qualification_vw]( we are getting Main_Qualification from this view):

```
SELECT  e.College_Year, 
e.Learner_ID,
a.Code AS Main_Qualification_Code,
MAX(b.IS_AS_Level_Umbrella) AS IS_AS_Level_Umbrella,
MAX(b.IS_A2_Level_Umbrella) AS IS_A2_Level_Umbrella,
-- Not took MAX belkow because there were two people doing both AS and A2 Levels. 
-- This will give them AS Level as Main Qualification.
MAX(CASE    WHEN b.IS_AS_Level_Umbrella = 'Yes' THEN 'AS Level' 
WHEN b.IS_A2_Level_Umbrella = 'Yes' THEN 'A2 Level'
ELSE a.Code END) AS Main_Qualification
,a.Code
FROM    IM_EN_ENROLMENTS_VW e
INNER JOIN ( 
-- Join to the query that gets the qual with the maximum GLH
SELECT A.COLLEGE_YEAR,
A.LEARNER_ID,
MAX(A.CODE) AS CODE,
A.GLH
FROM   (-- Get GKH of all Quals and join this to highest 
-- GLH the student has beteewn all Quals
SELECT   COLLEGE_YEAR,
LEARNER_ID,
CODE,
SUM(GLH) AS GLH
FROM     DBO.IM_EN_ENROLMENTS_VW
WHERE    (TYPE_OF_RECORD = 'Q')
AND (QUALIFICATION_MGMNT_CODE_1 NOT IN ('KS','TUT'))
AND (QUALIFICATION_MGMNT_CODE_3 NOT IN ('AD'))
AND (Code NOT LIKE ('%/N%'))
AND (Completion_Stat_Q19 <> '4')
GROUP BY COLLEGE_YEAR,LEARNER_ID,CODE) AS A
INNER JOIN (
-- Get the MAX GLH of all Quals
SELECT   COLLEGE_YEAR,
LEARNER_ID,
MAX(GLH) AS MAXGLH
FROM     (
-- Get GKH of all Quals
SELECT  COLLEGE_YEAR,
LEARNER_ID,
CODE,
SUM(GLH) AS GLH
FROM    DBO.IM_EN_ENROLMENTS_VW
WHERE    (TYPE_OF_RECORD = 'Q')
AND (QUALIFICATION_MGMNT_CODE_1 NOT IN ('KS','TUT'))
AND (QUALIFICATION_MGMNT_CODE_3 NOT IN ('AD'))
AND (Code NOT LIKE ('%/N%'))
AND (Completion_Stat_Q19 <> '4')
GROUP BY COLLEGE_YEAR,LEARNER_ID,CODE) AS V
GROUP BY COLLEGE_YEAR,LEARNER_ID) AS B
ON A.COLLEGE_YEAR = B.COLLEGE_YEAR
AND A.LEARNER_ID = B.LEARNER_ID
AND A.GLH = B.MAXGLH
AND A.COLLEGE_YEAR = B.COLLEGE_YEAR
group by  A.COLLEGE_YEAR,
A.LEARNER_ID,
A.GLH) AS a ON e.College_year = a.College_year AND e.Learner_ID = a.Learner_ID
LEFT JOIN (
-- Get AS and A2 Level Learners  
SELECT  College_Year, 
Learner_Id, 
Code,
dbo.IS_AS_Umbrella(College_Year, Code) AS IS_AS_Level_Umbrella,
dbo.IS_A2_Umbrella(College_Year, Code) AS IS_A2_Level_Umbrella
FROM    IM_EN_ENROLMENTS_VW 
WHERE   (dbo.IS_AS_Umbrella(College_Year, Code) = 'Yes' OR dbo.IS_A2_Umbrella(College_Year, Code) = 'Yes')
AND Type_Of_Record = 'Q') AS b ON e.College_Year = b.College_year
        AND e.Learner_ID = b.Learner_ID
GROUP BY 
e.College_Year, 
e.Learner_ID,
a.Code
```

IM_LU_Qualifications_vw(getting Qualification_Title from here):

```
SELECT  RTRIM(dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code) AS Qualification_Code, 
                CASE WHEN LEFT(PRPH_Code, 5) = 'S1500' OR PRPH_Code LIKE '15%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Is_AS_level, 
                RTRIM(dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Title) AS Qualification_Title,
                ------------------------------
                RTRIM(PRIL_Title) as Course_funding_Title, 
                PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Status,
                ------------------------------ 
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Year AS Qualification_Year, 
                RTRIM(dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_ML1) AS Qualification_Mgmnt_Code_1, 
                dbo.IM_LU_Departments_vw.Department, 
                RTRIM(dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_ML2) AS Qualification_Mgmnt_Code_2, 
                CASE WHEN RTRIM(dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Available_Enr) = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Available, 
                dbo.IM_LU_Sections_vw.Section, 
                RTRIM(dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_ML3) AS Qualification_Mgmnt_Code_3, 
                RTRIM(dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_FT_PT) AS Qualification_FT_PT, 
                ISNULL(RTRIM(dbo.PRCOCoordinators.PRCO_Tutor), '') AS Coordinator_Code, 

                ISNULL(PRFSFeesTuition.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Tuition_Fees, 

                /********* TUI24+FC ************ */
                ISNULL(FullCost_24plus.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS FullCost_24plus_Fees,

                ---------------
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesUniform.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Uniform_Fees,
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesKit.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Kit,
                --------------
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesMaterials.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Material_Fees,
                ------------------------Full Cost Material_Fees-----------------------------------------------------------
                ISNULL(FullCostMaterialsFees.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS FullCost_Material_Fees,

                /********* CRB ************ */
                ISNULL(CRB_Fees.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS CRB,
                ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesExam.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Exam_Fees,
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesTrainingCredit.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Training_Credit_TF, 
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesUserFee5.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Police_Check_Fees, 
                ISNULL(PRFSFeesOverseas.PRFS_Fee_Amount, 0) AS Overseas_Fees, 
                RTRIM(ISNULL(dbo.PRTTTutors.PRTT_Tutor, '')) AS Tutor, 
                dbo.PERSstaff.PERS_Forename AS Course_Leader_Forename, 
                dbo.PERSstaff.PERS_Surname AS Course_Leader_Surname, 
                RTRIM(dbo.PERSstaff.PERS_Department_ML) AS Tutor_Department, 
                IM_LU_Departments_vw.Department AS Tutor_Department_Description, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_GLH_A32 AS Qualification_GLH, 
                -------------------- Columns swapped around ------------  
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Hours_per_Week AS GLH_per_week,
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Annual_End_Date As Annual_End_Date,
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Annual_GLH AS Annual_GLH,
                --dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Hours_per_Week AS GLH_per_week,
                -------------------------------------------------------------- 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Length_Weeks AS Weeks_in_year, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Start_Date_A27 AS Qualification_Start_Date, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Exp_End_Date_A28 AS Qualification_End_Date, 
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Annual_Start_Date as Annual_Start_Date,
                -------------------- Columns swapped around ------------  
                --dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Aim_A09 AS Qual_Aim,
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Aim AS Qual_Aim,
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Title AS Aim_Title,
                --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                ------------------- Columns swapped around ------------  
                ISNULL(AV.FullLevel2Percent, 0)  AS Full_Level2_Percentage, 
                ISNULL(AV.FullLevel3Percent, 0)  AS Full_Level3_Percentage, 
                --ISNULL(dbo.LAAV_ALL_VALUES.LEVEL2_PERCENTAGE, 0) AS Full_Level2_Percentage, 
                --ISNULL(dbo.LAAV_ALL_VALUES.LEVEL3_PERCENTAGE, 0) AS Full_Level3_Percentage, 

                -------------------- Columns swapped around ------------  
                [dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery].NotionalNVQLevel AS NVQLevel, 
                [dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery].EntrySubLevel    as  Entry_SubLevel,
                [dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery].AwardOrgCode AS Awarding_Body,
        --      dbo.LAIM_AIMS.NOTIONAL_NVQ_LEVEL_CODE AS NVQLevel, 
        --      dbo.LAIM_AIMS.AWARDING_ORGANISATION AS Awarding_Body,

                --£££££££££££££££
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Year_Of AS QUAL_Year_of_Qual, 
                RTRIM(PRFSFeesCostRecovery.PRFS_Nominal) AS Cost_Recovery_AC, 
                RTRIM(PRFSFeesTuition.PRFS_Nominal) AS Tuition_Fees_AC, 
                Cost_Centres.Cost_Centre, 
                /********* TUI24+FC ************ */
                FC_Cost_Centres.FC_Cost_Centre,

                RTRIM(PRFSFeesTrainingCredit.PRFS_Nominal) AS Training_Credit_AC, 
                RTRIM(PRFSFeesExam.PRFS_Nominal) AS Exam_Fees_AC, 
                RTRIM(PRFSFeesMaterials.PRFS_Nominal) AS Material_Fees_AC, 
                RTRIM(PRFSFeesRegn.PRFS_Nominal) AS Regn_Fee_AC,
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Funding_A10 AS FEFC_Fund_Q10, 
                dbo.GNCDgncodes.GNCD_Description AS Funding_Description, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Max AS QUAL_Max_Size, 
                NULL AS National_Rate_1, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Length_Years AS No_Of_Years, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance AS Instance, 
                dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Type, 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Code AS Qual_Instance_Code, 
             --   dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_MOA AS MOA_Code, 
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Workplace_Learning AS WPL,
                ------------------- Columns swapped around ------------  
        --                      dbo.ALL_ANNUAL_VALUES.SSA_TIER1_CODE AS Subject_sector_area, 
                CASE WHEN [dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery].SectorSubjectAreaTier1 > 0 
                THEN RIGHT('0' + CAST(CAST([dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery].SectorSubjectAreaTier1 AS INT) AS VARCHAR),2) END AS Subject_sector_area, 
                --£££££££££££££
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Title as Marketing_Title,

                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Delivery_Postcode_A23,
                ------------------------------------------------
                RTRIM(dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Subject) as Sub_Section
                ------------------------------------------------                     
        FROM    dbo.PRILILR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader INNER JOIN
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance ON 
                dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRCOCoordinators ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = dbo.PRCOCoordinators.PRCO_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = dbo.PRCOCoordinators.PRCO_Instance

                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                [dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery] ON dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Aim COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = [dbo].[Core_LARS_LearningDelivery].[LearnAimRef] LEFT OUTER JOIN

                (SELECT [dbo].[Core_LARS_AnnualValue].*
                 FROM   [dbo].[Core_LARS_AnnualValue] INNER JOIN
                        (SELECT [LearnAimRef], MAX([EffectiveFrom]) LatestDate
                        FROM [dbo].[Core_LARS_AnnualValue]
                        GROUP BY LearnAimRef) LatestAV ON LatestAV.LearnAimRef = [dbo].[Core_LARS_AnnualValue].[LearnAimRef] AND LatestAV.LatestDate = [dbo].[Core_LARS_AnnualValue].[EffectiveFrom]) AV ON dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Aim COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = AV.LearnAimRef LEFT OUTER JOIN

                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesTuition ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesTuition.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesTuition.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesTuition.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'TUICF' --'TUI'
                /********* TUI24+FC ************ */
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS FullCost_24plus ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = FullCost_24plus.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = FullCost_24plus.PRFS_Instance AND (FullCost_24plus.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'TUI24+FC') 
                -----------------------
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesUniform ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesUniform.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesUniform.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesUniform.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'UNIFORM'

                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesKit ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesKit.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesKit.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesKit.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'Kit'
                --------------------

                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesCostRecovery ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesCostRecovery.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesCostRecovery.PRFS_Instance AND 
                PRFSFeesCostRecovery.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'COST REC'

                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesMaterials ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesMaterials.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesMaterials.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesMaterials.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'MAT' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                -----------------------------Full Cost Materials Fees---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                dbo.PRFSFees AS FullCostMaterialsFees ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = FullCostMaterialsFees.PRFS_Code AND
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = FullCostMaterialsFees.PRFS_Instance AND FullCostMaterialsFees.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'MATCF' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                -----------------------------CRB Fees---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                dbo.PRFSFees AS CRB_Fees ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = CRB_Fees.PRFS_Code AND
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = CRB_Fees.PRFS_Instance AND CRB_Fees.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'UCF5' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesExam ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesExam.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesExam.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesExam.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'EXM' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesTrainingCredit ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesTrainingCredit.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesTrainingCredit.PRFS_Instance AND 
                PRFSFeesTrainingCredit.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'TRAIN CRED' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesOverseas ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesOverseas.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesOverseas.PRFS_Instance AND 
                PRFSFeesOverseas.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'NONEU' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesRegn ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesRegn.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesRegn.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesRegn.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'REG' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRFSFees AS PRFSFeesUserFee5 ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = PRFSFeesUserFee5.PRFS_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = PRFSFeesUserFee5.PRFS_Instance AND PRFSFeesUserFee5.PRFS_Fee_Type = 'UCF5' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PRTTTutors ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = dbo.PRTTTutors.PRTT_Code AND 
                dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = dbo.PRTTTutors.PRTT_Instance LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.PERSstaff ON dbo.PRTTTutors.PRTT_Tutor = dbo.PERSstaff.PERS_Staff_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.IM_LU_Sections_vw ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_ML2 = dbo.IM_LU_Sections_vw.Section_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.IM_LU_Departments_vw ON dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_ML1 = dbo.IM_LU_Departments_vw.Department_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.IM_LU_Departments_vw AS IM_LU_Departments_vw1 ON dbo.PERSstaff.PERS_Department_ML = IM_LU_Departments_vw1.Department_Code ON 
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Code = dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code AND 
                dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Instance = dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.GNCDgncodes ON dbo.GNCDgncodes.GNCD_General_Code = dbo.PRILILR.PRIL_Funding_A10 AND 
                dbo.GNCDgncodes.GNCD_Code_Type = 'CH' AND dbo.GNCDgncodes.GNCD_Level <= 98 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (SELECT PRFS_Code AS Code, PRFS_Instance AS Instance, RTRIM(PRFS_Finance_Dept) AS Cost_Centre
                 FROM   dbo.PRFSFees
                 WHERE  (PRFS_Fee_Type = 'TUICF')--'TUI'
                 GROUP BY PRFS_Code, PRFS_Instance, PRFS_Finance_Dept) AS Cost_Centres ON 
                dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = Cost_Centres.Code AND dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = Cost_Centres.Instance

                /********* TUI24+FC ************ */
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (SELECT PRFS_Code AS Code, PRFS_Instance AS Instance, RTRIM(PRFS_Finance_Dept) AS FC_Cost_Centre
                 FROM   dbo.PRFSFees
                 WHERE  (PRFS_Fee_Type = ('TUI24+FC'))--'TUI'
                 GROUP BY PRFS_Code, PRFS_Instance, PRFS_Finance_Dept) AS FC_Cost_Centres ON 

                dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Code = FC_Cost_Centres.Code 
                AND dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance.PRPI_Instance = FC_Cost_Centres.Instance
                -------------------

        WHERE   (dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader.PRPH_Type = 'Q')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ar

Comment: Which column is of type `smallint`?

Comment: M.S - just checked it and none of them is smallint, both are varchar

Comment: Probably error is in the view IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw. Can you share its content and data type ?

Comment: Is it possible that your view contains a * in the select and that one of the underlying tables got a new column? In that case try running alter view. Better would be to specify all columns

Comment: @Ako - Please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw`. Your problem is that you are doing something like

> c1 + c2

where c1 and c2 are columns, c1 is of type `smallint`, c2 is textual and when the view was created, c2 contained only numeric values, but recently a textual data was added, which contains `'20PA'`. You need to change the view to convert c1 to textual data, using [CAST or CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

EDIT

As Aruna Raghuna pointed out, it turned out to be an issue in the College_Year column, which in at least a case, instead of the expected numeric value contained text as well. While I have shown the op the way to find the answer, frankly, it was Aruna, who searched for the issue. Thought process being used was as follows:

- check column types and find out which are of smallint types, so that we will know where to look for the problem
- check textual columns and find out which of those contained the text found in the error message
- possible final step is to fix either the query or the functionality along with the data, so this kind of issue will not be recurring in the future

Comment: Just checked the views,  datatypes are Main Qualification : Varchar(20) and Qualification_Title: Varchar(100)

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam, can you test your views? Which one contains the error? Can you describe the data type of each column? Which column contains '20PA' in any of the values?

Comment: I ran the query and none of the column have '20PA' :(

Comment: @Aruna, try to run queries which select values from the fields and check whether any of them contains '20PA'. (like '%20PA%'). Which one contains it?

Comment: Yes I ran both views individually and none of them returns any rows

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam, you are using columns in your views. At least one of the columns contains an element with that value. You need to check your columns, not your views.

Comment: Yes I have checked column in the view itself and it returns blank

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam, can you tell me how did you check the columns?

Comment: I checked in the source view: SELECT Qualification_Title
FROM [dbo].[IM_LU_Qualifications_vw]
where Qualification_Title LIKE '%20PA%'

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam, I wan to help you, but it seems you do not give me the information I need to do so. I asked you to check all the columns involved. You have checked a single column instead of all the columns and did not tell me the result, therefore I cannot help you unless you tell me the exact type of all columns involved along with columns having at least a record which contains 20PA. That value must come from somewhere. It might be the result of concatenation of 20 with PA as well. As things are standing, I have not enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: there are just 2 columns - Main_Qualification and Qualification_Title which are being used in dataset..what else should I be checking?

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam, those are in the highest level of your querying. But on the highest level I could not see syntactic errors. You need to check the columns used in the dependencies which you added to your question. There are a lot of columns, which makes the question too labor-intensive for us, SO users. You need to narrow the problem space by giving us the relevant information we can think about. To achieve this, we need to see the column names having smallint as type (that's a clue) and columns having values containing 20PA (another clue).

Comment: ok...there is a column Collge_Year datatype smallint, not null

Comment: Changed query to: select distinct CAST(College_Year AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ClgYear,
Main_Qualification,
               Main_Qualification + '  '+ Qualification_Title As Main_Qual_Title
from dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw
where CAST(College_Year AS VARCHAR(10)) = @College_Year
and Qualification_Title not Like '%CANX%'
order by Main_Qualification + '  '+ Qualification_Title

Comment: But Main dataset gives same error now: SELECT mq.Qualification_Title, mq.Main_Qualification + ' '+ mq.Qualification_Title As Main_Qualification_Title
FROM dbo.IM_EN_Enrolments_vw e
JOIN dbo.IM_ST_Students_vw st ON 
e.College_Year = st.College_Year 
LEFT JOIN IM_EX_Candidate_No_vw cn ON 
 e.College_Year = cn.College_Year
join dbo.IM_EN_Main_Qualifcation_with_title_vw mq ON     e.College_Year = mq.College_Year 
WHERE mq.Main_Qualification = Main_QualificationCode(Param)
AND e.College_Year = College_Year(Param)
GROUP BY mq.Qualification_Title, mq.Main_Qualification

Comment: Can you tell me which columns have values which contain 20PA?

Comment: I think it is College_Year

Comment: I have edited my answer to share the conclusions with others who might be helped by our conversation in the future.